# Deleting 2 items in a list box at the same time

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm tring to delete 2 items from a listbox at the same time, the first item is the information item and the secong item is just to create space between them.

This is the listbox with the items:

[image: Listbox]

I want to delete the **World** item and the the **blank item** after it.

I've tried this code :

```
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.SelectedIndex + 1);
```

the problem is that it's deleting all the items from the listbox or deleting differnt items.

to add the items to the listbox I use `Insert`

```
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "");
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "!");
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "");
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "World");
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "");
listbox1.Items.Insert(0, "Hello");
```

Comment: Once you remove the selected item, are you sure that there is something selected? What is the *exact* problem you are getting? - Also, [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why don't you set some margin on your listitems? Adding empty lines is not the right way.

Comment: I know but I want to have space between the items.

Comment: user, thats what the margin provides.

Comment: That is what the margin is for, to add space

Comment: Can you please explain more please, I'm trying to add margin but it doesn't work.

Comment: user2992413; You will need to do this on a template level. Dump the template in I.E blend and modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);`, you are removing the currently selected item.  That means that `listbox1.SelectedItem` and `listbox1.SelectedIndex` no longer point to what they did before.

Reversing the order of your calls is one way to avoid this.

```
listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.SelectedIndex + 1);
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.SelectedIndex + 1);//deletes the item below World
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);//deletes World
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind your collection to an ObservableCollection you won't have to deal with these problems.

Viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<String> items;
private String selectedItem;

public ObservableCollection<String> Items 
{
    get { return items; }
    set {
       if( items==value )// simplified
           return;
        items = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
    }
}

public String SelectedItem {...}
```

View:

```
<...
    <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}>
        <ListBox.TemplateStuffGoesHere/>
.../>
```

Do this inside a viewmodel that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface or forinstance uses galasofts mvvmlight viewmodelbase class as baseclass. Removing items should now work automaticly, when you just remove items from your list regardless. Messing directly with controls with nasty codebehind is a big no no =)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you tried,

```
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(listbox1.SelectedIndex + 1);
```

After

```
listbox1.Items.Remove(listbox1.SelectedItem);
```

the selected item is removed and those items behind the selected item are **reduced** their index by **1**(move forward). Besides that, the `listbox1.SelectedIndex` becomes **-1** also after that. At that moment,

```
listbox1.SelectedIndex + 1 = -1 + 1 = 0
```

Hence, you are doing

```
listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

That why you feel weird because you delete the **item you selected** and the **first item of new listbox list** (those items behind the selected item move forward).

In your case, you delete the "World" then delete the "Hello".

---

I suggest you to store the value of SelectedIndex and reuse it.

```
    int i = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

To delete *n* continuous lines included the selected item

```
    int i = listbox1.SelectedIndex;
    for (int j = 0; j < n;j++ )
        listbox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

All because all items index is updated after you remove an item.